# Read dynamically value of variable within variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have one json file tabs.json which having Format

```
{
"test":[
{
        "displayName": "1",
        "clickEvent": "open()",
        "hiddenProperty": "dashboard.privilege.ADDRESS_BOOK_ADMINISTRATE",
        "value": false
    },
{
        "displayName": "2",
        "clickEvent": "route()",
        "hiddenProperty": "dashboard.privilege.ADDRESS",
        "value": false
    },
]
}
```

In this file open(), route() are the click events present in test.component.ts file... To invoke them I am using

```
var data = tabs.json;
data.test.forEach((tab) => {
eval('this.' + tab.clickEvent);
});
```

This is working perfectly fine and its going to the function open(), route() etc

Similarly the values of "hiddenProperty" like "dashboard.privilege.ADDRESS_BOOK_ADMINISTRATE","dashboard.privilege.ADDRESS" are also the variables in test.component.ts file

I am trying to fetch the value of them

Tried like 
Example1:

```
var data = tabs.json;
data.test.forEach((tab) => {
eval('this.' + tab.hiddenProperty);
});
```

Result: Cannot read property 'dashboard' of undefined

Example2:

```
var data = tabs.json;
data.test.forEach((tab) => {
eval(tab.hiddenProperty);
});
```

Result: dashboard is not defined

Example3:

```
var data = tabs.json;
data.test.forEach((tab) => {
eval.call(this, tab.hiddenProperty);
});
```

Result: dashboard is not defined

Can you please suggest how can I access value of variable present within variable

Comment: Oh my. Don't program in JSON. JSON is not a programming language. JSON is a **data** format. It's not supposed to contain executable code.

Answer (score 0):

Json is a data format and it does not contain an executable code for that you could just define this structure in json :

```
"test":[
{
        "displayName": "1",
        "clickEvent": "0", // 0 for open and 1 for route
        "hiddenProperty": "0"// same thing 0 for one ts variable and 1 for the other,
        "value": false
    }
}
```

and then you can just put this code in your ts file :

```
data.test.forEach((tab) => {
if (tab.clickEvent){
this.route()
}else{
this.open()
}

});
```

same thing for variables hope i helped ;)